# CLR Stored Procedure

Tags: clr, clrstoredprocedure

I wish to use the Cryptography API in CLR stored procedure.

I have created a CLR stored procedure and written a select statement

```cs
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Context Connection=true";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = @"select * from Employee";

SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Now I wish to filter the results using the employee Number which is stored in encrypted form in database for which I am going to use the Cryptography methods.

Now I am stuck with how to go about filtering the records from the `SqlDataReader`.

I want the return format as `SqlDataReader`, as to return multiple records from CLR stored procedure there is one method `SqlContext.Pipe.Send()` and this method accepts only `SqlDataReader` objects.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at a similar problem where I want to do some manipulation before returning the results.
The only way I can see at the moment is to use:

```cs
// Note you need to pass an array of SqlMetaData objects to represent your columns
// to the constructor of SqlDataRecord

SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord();

// Use the Set methods on record to supply the values for the first row of data
SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart(record);

// for each record you want to return
// use set methods on record to populate this row of data

SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(record);
```

Then call `SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsEnd` when you're done.

If theres a better way I'd like to know too!

Comment: Instead of filtering the records after executing the command, I am writing a CLR Function which would do decryption for me. I would use this CLR Function in my where statement. Hence I would get the filtered records which I can send directly.